# Python cPickle: load fails with UnpicklingError

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I've made a pickle file using the following.

```
from PIL import Image
import pickle
import os
import numpy
import time

trainpixels = numpy.empty([80000,6400])
trainlabels = numpy.empty(80000)
validpixels = numpy.empty([10000,6400])
validlabels = numpy.empty(10000)
testpixels = numpy.empty([10408,6400])
testlabels = numpy.empty(10408)

i=0
tr=0
va=0
te=0
for (root, dirs, filenames) in os.walk(indir1):
    print 'hello'
    for f in filenames:
            try:
                    im = Image.open(os.path.join(root,f))
                    Imv=im.load()
                    x,y=im.size
                    pixelv = numpy.empty(6400)
                    ind=0
                    for ii in range(x):
                            for j in range(y):
                                    temp=float(Imv[j,ii])
                                    temp=float(temp/255.0)
                                    pixelv[ind]=temp
                                    ind+=1
                    if i<40000:
                            trainpixels[tr]=pixelv
                            tr+=1
                    elif i<45000:
                            validpixels[va]=pixelv
                            va+=1
                    else:
                            testpixels[te]=pixelv
                            te+=1
                    print str(i)+'\t'+str(f)
                    i+=1
            except IOError:
                    continue
trainimage=(trainpixels,trainlabels)
validimage=(validpixels,validlabels)
testimage=(testpixels,testlabels)

output=open('data.pkl','wb')

pickle.dump(trainimage,output)
pickle.dump(validimage,output)
pickle.dump(testimage,output)
```

Now I'm unpickling with load_data() function of the following code:
http://www.deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_sgd.py
which is called by running
http://www.deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/rbm.py

but it returns the following error.

```
cPickle.UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered,
but no persistent_load function was specified.
```

It seems like data structure is unmatched, but I can' figure out how it should be..

For reference, the size of the pickle file is over 16GB, with its gzip over 1GB

Comment: That's odd. You pickle three structures sequentially by I/O, then try to unpickle them as a tuple. Could you try picking them using `pickle.dump((trainimage, validimage, testimage), output)` ?

Comment: @SteveK Is that likely to solve the problem? It took about 3 hours to pickle the files, so with respect I'm a little hesitant to proceed without certainty...

Comment: @SteveK btw cPickle.load(f) itself seems to cause the error, so I'm not sure whether the way I unpickle them as a tuple is the cause..

Comment: I understand. I've found that pickling and unpickling is smart. But you don't unpickle the same way you pickle, so it cannot work. Here you want to unpickle a tuple but you have not pickled a tuple. 
What you have to do is open the file for unpickling, then `pickle.load` each of your objects sequentially.

Comment: what do you assign to `f`?

Comment: @shx2 I assigned this pkl.gz file..

Comment: It would help if you add that assignment to your question, because the problem likely lies there

Comment: @shx2 Thanx. I have pasted the links to the code by which I'm trying to unpickle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that pickling and unpickling is smart. 
Here you don't unpickle the same way you pickle, so it cannot work. In your code you pickle objects one after the other in the same file. You pickled three times to the same file.
If you want to read them back, you have to make sequential reading.
What you have to do is open the file for unpickling, then `pickle.load` each of your objects sequentially.

```
with gzip.open(dataset, 'rb') as f:
    train_set = cPickle.load(f)
    valid_set = cPickle.load(f)
    test_set = cPickle.load(f)
```

You might want to try a simpler code where `train_set, valid_set, test_set` (do the pickling and unpickling with gzip) are simple picklable objects, just to be sure.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it caused the same error.. :(

Comment: For your reference, I'm unpickling using load_data() of this code http://www.deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_sgd.py

Comment: Your edit now gives me a cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, ''. --> Could it be because I opened data.pkl.gz instead of data.pkl?

Comment: Does `data.pkl.gz` exist ? If it does, and you saved your objets the same way you load them (using a `gzip.open`ed file) in this file, there should not be issues

Comment: sorry it didn't work....:( It's still giving me the same persistent load error from     train_set=cPickle.load(f)..

Comment: Here I'm unfortunately stuck :( Maybe someone will come and see something new. Are you sure you saved the file using `gzip.open('', 'wb')` ?

Comment: No, I manually zipped the file from terminal by 'tar -cvzf data.pkl.gz data.pkl' Could it be the reason?

Comment: Maybe. If you gzip the file, try with the gzip command line instead. I think `tar` creates a compressed archive with the file inside, while `gzip` creates a compressed version of the file, which is what you want.

Comment: simply using gzip command with your code worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when using:

pandas.read_pickle('filepath_or_buffer') without specifying other pickling options. I saw that the original pickling had been done using :

```
compression='zip'
```

So I tried:

```
pandas.read_pickle('filepath_or_buffer', compression='zip', storage_options=None)
```

I appreciate this is not a direct answer to OPs question. But this question is the top google hit so I thought I'd add it here.