# OSError: Failed to interpret my file as a pickle (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, compiler-errors

I am trying to load a file, and it has worked before but now I only get the error:

> OSError: Failed to interpret file 'name.npz' as a pickle

The code I use is the following

```
data = np.load("name.npz")
```

I can't see what has changed since I last run the code and it worked, I even backed back to the original code (that I had when I'm sure it worked to load it) but it still gives the same error message.

Comment: I'd try to look at `name.npz` with an OS archive tool.  Given the name it should be a `zip` archive.  But `load` checks for an initial `archive` byte string, and failing that tries to open it conventionally, or (apparently) as a `pickle`.    It's possible the file has been corrupted.

Comment: @hpaulj but isn't it strange that I could open the file using the exact same code before without a problem?

Comment: Something must have happened to the file as you said, I downloaded it again and now it works without any problem

Answer (score 0):

You could open it as a raw pickle first and then convert to an numpy array as follow:

```
import pickle as pl
import numpy as np
myfile = "name.npz"
with open(myfile, 'rb') as handle:
     my_array = pl.load(handle)
data = np.array(my_array)
```

Comment: Then I get this error message:  

my_array = pl.load(handle)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered,
but no persistent_load function was specified.

Comment: Hmm, I did never face this error message. They are discussing it in the following thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151206/python-cpickle-load-fails-with-unpicklingerror

Comment: Seems like it depends on how the file has been pickled before

Answer (score 0):

have you tried np.fromfile() ?
see the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html)

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.